# SQLAlchemy ForeignKey can't find table

Tags: python, foreign-keys, sqlalchemy

Getting this error when I try to instantiate the `ConsumerAdvice` class.

```
Foreign key associated with column 'tbConsumerAdvice.ConsumerAdviceCategory_ID' 
could not find table 'tbConsumerAdviceCategories' with which to generate a
foreign key to target column 'ID_ConsumerAdviceCategories'
```

```
class ConsumerAdviceCategory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbConsumerAdviceCategories'
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'dbo'}
    ID_ConsumerAdviceCategories = Column(INTEGER, Sequence('idcac'),\
            primary_key=True)
    Name = Column(VARCHAR(50), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self,Name):
        self.Name = Name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "< ConsumerAdviceCategory ('%s') >" % self.Name

class ConsumerAdvice(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbConsumerAdvice'
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'dbo'}
    ID_ConsumerAdvice = Column(INTEGER, Sequence('idconsumeradvice'),\
            primary_key=True)
    ConsumerAdviceCategory_ID = Column(INTEGER,\
            ForeignKey('tbConsumerAdviceCategories.ID_ConsumerAdviceCategories'))
    Name = Column(VARCHAR(50), nullable=False)
    Category_SubID = Column(INTEGER)

    ConsumerAdviceCategory = relationship("ConsumerAdviceCategory",\
            backref=backref('ConsumerAdvices'))

    def __init__(self,Name):
        self.Name = Name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "< ConsumerAdvice ('%s') >" % self.Name
```

Comment: Do not know why, but if you remove the `schema` from `__table_args__`,it works (tested with SQLite). Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: ... try to define the FK including schema: `dbo.tbConsumerAdviceCategories.ID_ConsumerAdviceCategories`

Comment: @van It's MSSQL and adding the schema to the FK definition worked!  Much KUDOS.. can you add the answer so I can mark it answered?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Define the FK including schema: `dbo.tbConsumerAdviceCategories.ID_ConsumerAdviceCategories`

Answer (score 8):

I also hit this error.  In my case the root cause was that I attempted to define different sqlalchemy base classes:

```
Base1 = declarative_base(cls=MyBase1)
Base1.query = db_session.query_property()

Base2 = declarative_base(cls=MyBase2)
Base2.query = db_session.query_property()
```

I had a `ForeignKey` relationship from one class that derives from `Base1` to another class that derives from `Base2`.  This didn't work -- I got a similar `NoReferencedTableError`.  Apparently classes must derive from the same Base class in order to know about each other.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

That didn't solve my problem, I had to use.

```
ConsumerAdviceCategory_ID = Column(INTEGER,
            ForeignKey('tbConsumerAdviceCategories.ID_ConsumerAdviceCategories',  
            schema='dbo'))
```

Comment: I don't understand how you did it to make it work, because adding such of a parameter throws a `TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>`.